# Prove the limit of the integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

Suppose:
$f:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)\in C^2[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $\gamma=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/2+\dotsb+1/n-\ln{n})$.

Prove:$$  \lim_{s\to +\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}f(x)\,dx- \frac{\pi}{2}f(0)s-\frac{f'(0)}{2}\ln{s}\right)= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{f(x)-f(0)-f'(0)x}{2\sin^2x}\,dx+\frac{f'(0)}{2}(1+\ln2+\gamma)  .    
$$

I can only prove that$$\lim_{s\to +\infty}\frac{1}{s}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}f(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}f(0).$$

I think we can calculate the asymptotic expansion of $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}f(x)\,dx$ (as $s \to +\infty$), but it is hard for me.

Comment: Welcome to MO!  Editorialising about the difficulty of the problem usually doesn't belong, especially in the title, so I have removed it.

Comment: What is the origin of this question, if I may ask?

Comment: I learn mathematics by watching a math video dedicated to a math creator.He always .He always explains some particularly difficult competition questions in our country.For this question,he only proves  that$$\lim_{s\to +\infty}\frac{1}{s}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(sx)}{\sin^2x}f(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}f(0).$$,and he left the question I mentioned as a reflection question.